# Comparing a Scanner to a String

Tags: java, string, compare

I'm trying to ask the user to enter a character ("y"/"n") and check whether or not that was the right answer. I'm getting the following error: "incomparable types: java.util.Scanner and java.lang.String"

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.printf("Is this word spelled correctly?: %s", wordToCheck);
        rightCheck(userInput);
```

---

```
public boolean rightCheck(Scanner usersAnswer)
{
    if(usersAnswer == "y")
    {
        //"Correct!"
        //Increment User's Score
    }
    else
    {
        //"Incorrect"
        //Decrement User's Score
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code, haven't tested it but it should work:

```
 Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Is this word spelled correctly?:" + wordToCheck);
        rightCheck(userInput.next());//send the string rather than the scanner

public boolean rightCheck(String usersAnswer)//convert the parameter type to String
{
    if(usersAnswer == "y")
    {
        //"Correct!"
        //Increment User's Score
    }
    else
    {
        //"Incorrect"
        //Decrement User's Score
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, because a scanner is a *way of getting input* rather than the value itself. You want to fetch the next value from the input, and then compare it. Something like this:

```
String answer = scanner.next();
if (answer.equals("y")) {
    ...
} else if (answer.equals("n")) {
    ...
}
```

Note that you should usually (including this case) *not* compare strings with `==`, as that compares whether the two operands refer to the exact same string object - you're only interested in whether they refer to *equal* objects. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more details.)

Comment: you could make the program less error-prone by switching the arguments of `equals`:

`"y".equals(answer)`

This will not throw `NullPointerException` if `answer` is `null`

Comment: @cIph3r: `Scanner.next()` never returns null, so there's no need to do that here. If it ever *did* return null, that would indicate that something's very broken - so I'd rather know about it via an exception than continue in a world of brokenness.

Comment: ok, right. I the case of `scanner.next()`, there is no null-value. But in general, this prevents such errors.

Comment: @cIph3r: My point is that something it *prevents* errors - but in other cases it *propagates* them. You should always know whether or not you're expecting that a string can be null - and decide what to do based on that assumption. If the assumption is wrong, I'd rather know about it sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should first get the String from Scanner (through next() maybe?). Then in your method, do not use "==" as a string comparator.